# Spring Security UI, recommendation on other complementary Forms / UI plugins

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

The Spring Security UI has a very nice interface and menuing system.  I'm wondering if you can recommend which other Grails Form / UI plugins would be most complementary.  My UI needs are ajax/dynamic form validation, popups, calendars, and limited shopping cart functionality.

Thanks

Comment: I guess it is anything made with JQuery that is ideal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your input, I would go for the [jQuery](http://www.grails.org/plugin/jquery), [jQueryUI](http://www.grails.org/plugin/jquery-ui) (for your UI widgets) and the [Spring Webflow](http://www.grails.org/plugin/webflow) plugins.

Comment: I'll look further into the Spring Webflow plugins -- thanks for your comments Hans.

Comment: possibly you could be interested in the ajaxflow plugin...
i suppose you can mark my answer as the answer to your question then?